# How does comparison work if the __lt__ protocol isn't implemented?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison

I am mostly interested in terms of what is happening but lets say I have a custom class with __eq__ implemented and nothing else.

How do the other comparisons get resolved? What is the default behaviour? Every time I run the comparison I get a different result. I know that I need to implement these and that I can also use `@total_ordering` to simplify the job.

What is actually happening behind the scenes? This is mostly out curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `__lt__` isn't defined, comparisons use `__cmp__` instead.  If that's not defined, it uses a default comparator.  And it appears that the default comparator compares by "object identity (address)".

See [the docs for `__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) for details.

Comment: link to some documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Some additional information from [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) section of the Python documentation:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result).
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.